# amazonka: catch exceptions that meet certain criteria

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I am using the excellent `amazonka` library.

I have one function where I need to make an `updateItem` to a `DynamoDB` table. The update includes a condition expression.

If the update succeeds then my function returns `True` (in the application monad). If the update throws a `ServiceError` with `ErrorCode` equal to `ConditionalCheckFailed` then my function returns `False`. All other exceptions are caught by the function caller.

In other words I want the function to return `True` on a successful update to the table, `False` otherwise and I want to throw all exceptions other than the one above as normal.

My problem is that I don't know how to check whether a `ServiceError` with the above `ErrorCode` is thrown.

This is what I have tried (`try` is from `Control.Monad.Catch` and returns `m (Either e a)`, bracketed numbers in first column correspond to line numbers in the error further below):

```
[41]    rs <- try $ send $ updateItem "TableName" & uiKey ...blah blah
        case rs of
[47]      Left e  -> if (serviceCode e) == (errorCode "ConditionalCheckFailed")
                     then return False else throwM e
          Right _ -> return True
```

`errorCode` is the constructor for the type `ErrorCode`. `serviceCode` is a `lens` that pulls the service code out of the error.

I also tried to use `tryJust`:

```
rs <- try' $ send $ updateItem "TableName" & uiKey ...blah blah
where try' = tryJust (\e -> if (serviceCode e) == (errorCode "ConditionalCheckFailed") then Nothing else Just e)
```

In both cases I seem to have trouble getting the predicate `if (serviceCode e) == (errorCode "ConditionalCheckFailed")` to type check (I don't understand lenses well):

```
    Couldn't match expected type ‘ServiceError -> f1 ServiceError’
                with actual type ‘ErrorCode’
    Relevant bindings include
      e :: ErrorCode -> f1 ErrorCode
        (bound at src/Foo.hs:47:10)
      rs :: Either (ErrorCode -> f1 ErrorCode) UpdateItemResponse
        (bound at src/Foo.hs:41:3)
    Possible cause: ‘errorCode’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely
      ‘(errorCode "ConditionalCheckFailed")’
    In the expression:
      (serviceCode e) == (errorCode "ConditionalCheckFailed")
```

How can I get something like this to work?

Comment: Here's link to amazonka: https://github.com/brendanhay/amazonka/ .

Also, submitting the type-error might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [one of lens' exception handling function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Exception-Lens.html#g:1) along with [lens exception](https://github.com/brendanhay/amazonka/blob/020bc7bde47bb235e448c76088dc44d6cec13e9b/amazonka-dynamodb/gen/Network/AWS/DynamoDB/Types.hs#L19-L38) predefined in `amazonka`.
Something along the lines of:

```
handling _ConditionalCheckFailedException ({- your handling code goes here -}) $
  do send $ updateItem "TableName" & uiKey ...blah blah
```

[Also amazonka docs](https://github.com/ambiata/amazonka/blob/develop/amazonka/src/Control/Monad/Trans/AWS.hs#L492-L505)